# Long refrigerator line in split AC

Tags: hvac, mini-split

I'm considering a split AC/heat pump install for my house. However, one set of location (compressor on the ground, air outlet on second floor) would require running the refrigerant 15 vertical feet up, and another 15 horizontal feet through the house.

Would this be too long a line?

Or, to be more specific:

- Does the efficiency a split system decrease in proportion to the length of the refrigerant line, due to it not flowing as well? Or is it similar to water piping where pressure is transmitted efficiently even for longer lines?
- When shopping for a split system, how do I tell that it can handle the length I'm planning? Do I just assume the length of the hose it comes with is the limit? Is it in the manual? Is there a specific term for maximum refrigerant line length?
- There will be several 90 degree turns in this line: When going from vertical to horizontal, and when going between rooms. How much of an effect would these have, assuming some reasonable turn radius (ie. not just a right angle elbow)?
- How important is it for the horizontal part to have a gentle decline? Can I make it perfectly level, or does it need to slightly angle downwards?

I know there is a similar question, [Would a long refrigerant line reduce the efficiency of a heat pump?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/239643). However, the answer was not helpful and it seems like this person's issue is some other problem, like an air leak, rather than the refrigerant line.

Comment: Read the specifications on the units you are considering. For some, perhaps yes, for many/most no.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with going up 15’ then 15’ horizontal, even if the horizontal line is not horizontal or slightly sloped but sloped to the compressor is best!  there is no big deal in the line set,

I have seen linesets that were 12-14” sag along much longer horizontal runs.
Now the important part the line set needs to be properly sized. Size increase fore 90’s if there a lot(use 90 sweeps it helps)

If the line set is longer than the pre charge additional refrigerant will need to be added!

Install linesets that are fully insulated, they cost more neoprene foam on both the little high pressure and the big low pressure line and Bob is your uncle.

If you have a long line set without additional refrigerant or insulation it will not work well and or will fail much sooner than a properly insulated and charged system.

Comment: Good point about the refrigerant amount. Should I assume that pre-charged products only have sufficient refrigerant for the exact length of line they come with, and anything extra would require adding refrigerant?